# CAD To GeoJSON after publishing it shows the job failed

Tags: arcpy, geojson, json, cad

I have written the code for CAD to GeoJSON. When I ran ArcMap or ArcCatalog it's working fine, after publishing the code it's giving the error. The code is too long. Can you provide the code

ArcGIS Manager Error description:

[image]

Tool Properties and Result in Catalog
[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide the full error message?

Comment: You've got a monstrously large chunk of code when it seems that the error occurs immediately. Please [Edit] the question to include the error as text in the body of the question and strip the script down to just parameter parsing. Then you could give more details about how it is being invoked.